# Show lines that start equally and end differently

Tags: beyondcompare, beyondcompare4

I have 2 log files with too many differences and absolutely different line order, however, there must be some lines that start equally but end with either "SUCCESS" or "NAME NOT FOUND". How do I make BeyondCompare show me only such lines, if at all possible? If I can't, is there any software that would allow it? Thank you.

Comment: is there a common width of your the equal lines? Something to say: the first x characters must be the same to determine similar lines. Another hint: With F7 you can align lines. Sometimes you must just align some lines to detect following equalities

Answer (score 0):

In the Text Compare, click the dropdown on the right side of the Format toolbar button and select the **Sorted** file format. It will run an alphanumeric sort of lines in the files before they're opened for comparison.

If sorting isn't enough, you can also edit file format and importance settings to make only the text "SUCCESS" and "NAME NOT FOUND" important and hide all other text differences.

1. First, define a new grammar element.
2. In the Text Compare, click the Rules toolbar button.
3. In the Importance tab, click Edit Grammar.
4. Click + in the top of the tab.
5. Name the element, then enter SUCCESS as the text matching.
6. Click OK twice.
7. In the Grammar element list, check the new element you listed,
   uncheck all other elements to make them unimportant.
8. Click OK.

After you've defined the new grammar element, only the text SUCCESS will show as important if **View > Ignore Unimportant Differences** is turned on.